# Zeros of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $$f(z)=\gamma + z^{\beta_2-\beta_1}$$
where $\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$, $\beta_1\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\beta_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\beta_2 > \beta_1$. The variable $z$ takes complex values.

Is there a way of expressing the zeros of $f(z)$ in terms of the parameters ($\gamma,\beta_1,\beta_2$)?

Comment: In that case there would only be one root but there are actually $\beta_2 - \beta_1$, right?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-wrote. Here's a correction: setting $n = \beta_2 - \beta_1$, the roots are $z = -\gamma(\cos(2\pi k/n) + i \sin(2 \pi k/n))$, $k=0,...,n-1$.